# Apache: set aside specific number of servers for a single "high priority" script

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-perl

I have a bunch of scripts, but some of them are higher priority than others:

```
/var/www/normal-priority/script1.pl
/var/www/normal-priority/script2.pl
/var/www/normal-priority/script3.pl
```

and

```
/var/www/high-priority/script1.pl
/var/www/high-priority/script2.pl
/var/www/high-priority/script3.pl
```

All running under mod-perl.  They reside in separate directories.

From time to time, the normal-priority scripts get very busy, and the httpd servers "swamp out" the less frequently called high priority ones.

Is it possible to set aside n httpd servers so that they only listen for the "high priority" scripts?

Comment: Do they have to run under httdp or could they just run standalone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive [RLimitNPROC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitnproc) to limit the number of processes allowed to start  in e.g. a directory. Since you're keeping the scripts in separate directories, this should work:

```
<Directory /var/www/high-priority>
  RLimitNPROC Max
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/normal-priority>
  RLimitNPROC 4711  # Change this number to something that works for you
</Directory>
```

You can also set limits for [CPU](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu) and [memory usage](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitmem).